How do I make Chrome remember my tab group order after a crash or power loss?
How can I ensure Chrome remembers my tab group order after a crash or power loss?
The best way to show what I mean is this screenshot:

I've tried a few things, like Chromium's built-in Save Tab Group functionality and the Session Buddy extension, but neither work to remember the tab group order.
This is a long-standing bug that I'm pretty sure has been around since tab groups were first introduced to Chromium.
EDIT
Since posting this question I've tried 3 different Session Manager extensions and 5 different Tab Group Management extensions. None of them change the default behavior of Chromium browsers restoring after a crash with tab groups arranged incorrectly.
